# ImportError at /first-page/ cannot import name Flatpage

Tags: django, importerror, django-flatpages

I am learning from *Practical Django Projects 2nd Edition*. When I start a new app named search like the examples in the book, I came across this problem.

I don't know why I cannot import this name in the model

```
Environment:
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/first-page/

Django Version: 1.5.5
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'cms.search',
 'django.contrib.flatpages')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  103.                     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  319.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  347.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  342.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/home/magic/workspace/projects_py/cms/cms/urls.py" in <module>
  21.         url(r'^search/',include('cms.search.views.search'))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  25.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/home/magic/workspace/projects_py/cms/cms/search/views.py" in <module>
  5. from django.contrib.flatpages.models import Flatpage

Exception Type: ImportError at /first-page/
Exception Value: cannot import name Flatpage
```

Comment: The class name is `FlatPage`, not `Flatpage`.

Comment: You are right!Thanks~